# Should there be nylon seals between a basin and taps?

Tags: bathroom

I have just had a new bathroom installed and the plumber has not put any rubber or nylon seals between the basin and bath taps that are placed on ceramic fixtures. Should there be seals between ?

Comment: Can you post a picture?

Comment: Did he use plumber's putty instead? It may be hard to determine if it's properly installed unless you watched the whole process. If it hasn't leaked yet, you're probably good.